# Creating an in-app tutorial on how to use the iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I created an app that I would like to have a tutorial open every time they open the app until they dismiss it.

I envision the user opening the app, being greeted by some page explaining its a tutorial, and then going through step by step showing how to use different aspects of the app. I could imagine doing this simply with screen shots and buttons to go to the next tip, but I was just wondering if anyone has ever done this and has any advice or an easier way to do it (like maybe filming actual use of the app and just loading the video, etc)

An example of this is if you have ever played Trainyard Express and it shows you how to build tracks and different techniques to accomplish each puzzle

Comment: This question is a bit broad if you ask me. You risk getting down voted.

Comment: I mean its not broad cause I am asking the best way to perform a task.. not all the code to do it.

Comment: This really is too broad for Stack Overflow. We're well suited for _specific_ questions that can solicit a best answer. Our sister site, programmers.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this. I didn't migrate it automatically because I had to read your question several times in order to finally understand what you were trying to do. You could try asking there, but keep in mind that you're much more familiar with your problem than we are, so some visual aids would definitely get you a better response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was implementing this, I would just use a simple text pop-up (maybe a UIAlertView or ModalView) on each view of the app that would describe the functions of that view. There could then be button options to dismiss the tutorial, or to dismiss the tutorial and never show it again.